# Multiple Bolts and Wizard Edge

Tags: savage-worlds

If someone casts the power *Bolt* and casts multiple bolts at once, he rolls multiple attacks for those. So the caster rolls 1-3 psionic rolls + 1 wild die (similar to a weapon shooting multiple shots), depending on the number of targets, determining hits like with a ranged attack.

Do each of those gain the benefits from raises when the caster has the Wizard edge? (costs go down 1 Power Point per Raise)? If multiple dice roll a raise, do I reduce the number of power points multiple times?

I'm referring to the German version of *Savage Worlds*: Gentleman's Edition Revised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the power point cost when using the Bolt power and the Wizard Edge, the [official Pinnacle answer](http://www.peginc.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=45543) provided by Clint Black is as follows:

> Each die applies to the casting of that single specific bolt for activation which also determines the effect of Wizard.
>
> Raises from one die don't affect the cost of casting the other bolts at all only the specific bolt it applies to, where each it treated as its own 1 PP spell.
>
> So a character with Wizard who casts 3 bolts at 1 PP each would have to get a raise on all three dice to reduce the cost to 0.

In other words, you consider the power point cost of each bolt individually. The individual rolls for each of them determine which bolts get the benefit of the Wizard Edge. Some, all, or none of them may have their cost reduced.

This also applies if each bolt costs more than 1 power point (e.g. the Trapping that adds Armor Piercing for an additional Power Point). Essentially you would have up to three 2 Power Point bolts, which have their cost individually reduced for each raise on their dice.